# how to get best search results AND , OR , LIKE

Tags: sql, select, search, sql-like

### Query #1:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
FROM `table`
WHERE (
`title` LIKE '%this is search%'
)
OR (
`title` LIKE '%this%'
AND `title` LIKE '%is%'
AND `title` LIKE '%search%'
)
OR (
`title` LIKE '%this%'
OR `title` LIKE '%is%'
OR `title` LIKE '%search%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

but not works good , and when I try splited this sql:

### Query #2:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE (
    `title
` LIKE '%this is search%'
    )
```

**or**

### Query #3:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT `title`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE (
`title` LIKE '%this%'
    AND `title` LIKE '%is%'
    AND `title` LIKE '%search%'
```

**or** etc ...

returns different results

Comment: What is your actual question? Please elaborate.

Comment: my question is how i can get best search results whitout fulltext search

Comment: By best search results do you mean most similar to the search or the most results returned? I am also confused by what you want here.

Comment: Yes, do you want an exact string match, must it contain all words, or is a single word match enough in a multi word search?
Using the natural language search has benefit of providing a score column, thus ordering on relevance is simpler

Answer (score 4):

You are providing too little information, but from what I can see, you are looking for mySQL's [**fulltext search**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) functions.

- [**Boolean full-text searches**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) allow you to require and exclude words using `+` and `-`
- [**Natural language searches**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) match against a list of words, and return a weighted result set.